# Phone Input field flag and name of country

Tags: react-phone-number-input

I have used PhoneInput. It is working perfectly but I want name along with flag but in this code only flag is showing. Can it possible to show both name and flag of country.
Here is my code-

```
 <PhoneInput  className="bcont" value={user.bcontact} onChange={bcontact => setUser({ bcontact })}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Use the PhoneInput.getCountryData() method to retrieve an array of country data objects. Each object in the array contains a name and flag property. Then, use the array index of the selected country to display the corresponding name and flag.
2. Use the PhoneInput.onCountryChange() event to trigger a function that updates the state with the selected country's name and flag.
3. Use the PhoneInput.formatNumber() method to format the phone number as a string with the country code and name. The country code can be used to lookup the country name and flag from an external data source.